# Unable to install tp_smapi 0.41 on Thinkpad T500

Tags: 15.04, make, tlp, tp-smapi

I have downloaded tp_smapi module for my Thinkpad T500 using the steps in [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi) and ran make. it encountered no errors

```
root@Forge:/storage/Repository/git/tp_smapi# make install HDAPS=1 FORCE_IO=1
make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build M=/storage/Repository/git/tp_smapi O=/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 3 modules
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
rm -f /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/{thinkpad_ec,tp_smapi,tp_base}.ko
rm -f /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/firmware/{thinkpad_ec,tp_smapi,tp_base}.ko
rm -f /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/kernel/extra/{thinkpad_ec,tp_smapi,tp_base}.ko
rm -f /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/hdaps.ko
rm -f /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/kernel/extra/hdaps.ko
make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build M=/storage/Repository/git/tp_smapi O=/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
  INSTALL /storage/Repository/git/tp_smapi/hdaps.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /storage/Repository/git/tp_smapi/thinkpad_ec.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /storage/Repository/git/tp_smapi/tp_smapi.ko
Can't read private key
  DEPMOD  3.19.0-18-generic
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
depmod 3.19.0-18-generic
```

But when i tried to view the status of the battery using tlp, it shows as not loaded/installed:

```
root@Forge:/storage/Repository/git/tp_smapi# tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 0.7 --------------------------------------------

+++ ThinkPad Extended Battery Functions
tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (unsupported hardware)

+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = SONY
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 92P1141
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  56160 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  39310 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  39310 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Full
```

I have followed the steps provided on the sites to the best of my knowledge, but am unsure as to why the module is not installed.

- OS: Xubuntu 15.04 LTS
- Module code: [tp_smapi-GitHub](https://github.com/evgeni/tp_smapi)
- Kernel: 3.19.0-18-generic (x86-64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many instructions at thinkwiki.org are *very* outdated.

Just install the package from the Ubuntu repos:

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms
```

(as described in [TLP's docs](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation) too)

Comment: i have tried to do so & restarted, system says "tp-smapi-dkms is already the newest version."and tlp-stat shows the same error message about tp_smapi load error.

Comment: Lets see what happens if you load by hand:   `sudo modprobe -v tp_smapi force_io=1`   and don't reboot afterwards, just check with   `sudo tlp-stat -b`

Comment: I am getting a the following error message:

    `sol@Forge:~$ sudo modprobe -v tp_smapi force_io=1` 
    `insmod /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/extra/thinkpad_ec.ko` 
    `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'tp_smapi': No such device or address`

Comment: I have found the issue - there is no current conf file `/etc/modprobe.conf`, I have found that we need to create a new conf file in `/etc/modprobe.d` folder which i did & added the load with options for both modules. `options thinkpad_ec force_io=1
\n options tp_smapi hdaps=1 force_io=1
`