# problem with tp_smapi on ubuntu 15.4 lenovo thinkpad e440

Tags: 15.04, lenovo, tp-smapi

I can not load tp_smapi on my ubuntu15.4 lenovo thikpad e440. I get the following error :

```
  modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'tp_smapi': No such device or address
```

Answer (score 0):

In [these comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630429/unable-to-install-tp-smapi-0-41-on-thinkpad-t500#comment897635_630546), someone had the same problem, and apparently he found a solution. It didn't work for me though. Maybe for you it does.